# Movilizer - queryMasterdata use of like

Tags: mobile, movilizer

I have a mastedata entry like the following:

`<update key="100441337" group="G1" filter1="08243"`

When I execute a queryMasterdata with filter object:

`"and":
   "op": "like"
   "col": "filter1"
   "value": "08"`

It is not returning the value, anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "value": "%08%"
```

... will do the trick. For like searches the % "wildcards" have to be used